# Is there an 'iotop' equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows

What would be the equivalent for [iotop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29#Other_system_performance_commands) for Windows? Task Manager isn't enough for me.

Comment: This question is similar and might help you: http://superuser.com/questions/77351/tracking-disk-i-o-by-application-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try process explorer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653