# Accumulate I/O for windows?

Tags: windows-7, io

I have read about perfmon in [Tracking disk I/O by application in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/77351/tracking-disk-i-o-by-application-in-windows)

However, I am looking for something that doesn't show the current byte/s rates, but the total amount as if you were running `iotop -aoP` on linux. Is there any application that can do that on Windows 7? I want to let a program run for some time to see how much it does in **total**.

Comment: Windows' in-built Resource Monitor?

Comment: Like I said in the my question, that only shows the current I/O rates, not how much I/O has been done in total.

Comment: "Performance Monitor" (PerfMon) =/= "[Resource Monitor](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/learn-how-to-use-the-windows-7-resource-monitor-for-effective-troubleshooting/)".

Comment: Oh right, I have tried that one too, but only Byte/sec there as well. No total counters AFAIK

Comment: Ahh gotcha, you should mention what you've tried already and what the results were, helps avoid us suggesting things you already tried. :)  Did you also try Ms'/Systernals' Process Monitor as suggested in the other answer on the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft/Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) does have this ability.

Add the column "I/O Write Bytes" (or Read/Total) to your view. The displayed number is a counter of all relevant I/O activity for the process, from an OS counter. Covers activity from before before Process Explorer was started.