# How to diagnose a lagging Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, speed, lag, diagnostic

### ***Symptoms***

Windows 7 laptop is suddenly responding very slowly.  For example, clicking on the sound icon in the system tray takes about 5 seconds to display the volume control.  Interestingly, it only lags about 80% of the time.  One in five attempts to bring up the volume control results in it displaying immediately.

Volume control is just an example.  Similarly, opening Notepad takes 3-5 seconds instead of being almost instantaneous.  Opening Calculator also takes 3-5 seconds.  Typically, these operations are near-instantaneous.

### *What's Interesting*

Opening Windows Explorer by pressing Win+E still loads Windows Explorer almost instantly.

Operations that don't involve a lot of OS interaction, work just fine.  For example, typing into Notepad or using Calculator work just fine.

### *What's Unusual*

The Windows Task Manager does ***not*** show high CPU utilization while waiting for simple tasks to complete, such as loading the volume control.

### *More Details*

Until a few days ago, the system worked perfectly.  There is very little installed on the computer (about 15 applications outside of Windows itself).

So what changed since a few days ago?  Two things: There was an update to Evernote, and I connected a Motorola Android smartphone for the first time.

### *What I've Tried*

1. Ran two anti-virus scanners and scanned everything - nothing found
2. Ran Spybot - Search and Destroy - nothing found
3. Ran Autoruns by Sysinternals - nothing unusual found
4. Ensured there is no bloatware installed.
5. Verified that CPU utilization is at 0-5% when the system is idle.

### *Question*

What's next in the process of diagnosing this issue and resolving it?

Comment: A fresh installation. Try a different hard drive(so fresh install and fresh drive), and/Try installing windows on a new partition of the smae hard drive(so fresh windows same drive)

Comment: Most of the times, when I experienced unexplained delays in applications responding to my actions, it was caused by a storage device that was about to fail.  A device that has lots of errors, when it's being read, will cause Windows to wait for it to respond to its last requests.  When I experienced faults like this, the machine would work most of the time, then out of the blue decide it would take an hour to bring up the task manager.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Besides looking at SMART values, any other way to verify drive integrity?

Comment: I'm on windows 10, in the same boat as you @RockPaperLizard

Comment: @Nick Maybe we can figure this out by seeing what's in common.  What Anti-Virus is running on that machine?  Is Evernote installed?  Any new Android devices connected to it recently?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I don't have any antiviruses I installed myself, so Windows Defender is the only antivirus. Yes, evernote is installed. I had a vivo phone (that ran funtouch OS) that I copied 100GB of media off last year, I don't know what could be causing the lag.

Answer (score 0):

next step is  drivers verification,  from here see [Consider this an absolute must - manually updating your drivers.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-computer-lagging-and-running-slow/da4b8c08-43e9-4562-9068-6c0a298728bd?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

You mention two antivirus scanners - are you sure that you are running exactly one? I once had two scanners running at once and it made the notebook so unusable it required a format.

Does opening other applications take longer then usual as well? My bet is on something abusing your hard-drive - maybe Evernote is indexing something? Or Windows has some indexes? Checking what is using the drive is explained in [another SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/77354/403314).

As for explorer starting instantly - that's explained by the fact that explorer is part of the Windows shell - without the process there would be no start bar or desktop icons.

Comment: One AV is installed, and the other is on-demand.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard well, what about stuff using hard-drive? Especially if you have an HDD. Also does the system freeze when loading stuff?